Not able to update data on specific fields on elastic Search
I am intending  to update certain fields on an elastic document, lets say if there are 10 fields in an elastic document , i only intend to update 3 or 4 fields out of 10 fields ,  i am using elastic 8.10.4 , for some reason , it says it is not  able to take the script field and says Cannot resolve method 'script(Script) , is it because of elastic Version, any insights would be helpful!!
public void upsertNvalueDataToESByQuery(List<SearchNValue> searchNvalues, String index, boolean isPreview, String attributeId_s, String formattedName_s, String displayName) {
        List<Query> queryList = new ArrayList<>();
        queryList.add(MatchQuery.of(matchQueryBuilder -> matchQueryBuilder.field(attributeId_s).query(""))._toQuery());

        StringBuilder scriptBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        scriptBuilder.append("ctx._source.NAME = params.name; ");
        scriptBuilder.append("ctx._source.DISP_NAME = params.displayName; ");


        Script script = new Script(
                ScriptType.INLINE,
                "painless",
                scriptBuilder.toString(),
                ImmutableMap.of(
                        "name", formattedName_s,
                        "displayName", displayName
                ));

        UpdateByQueryRequest updateByQueryRequest = new UpdateByQueryRequest.Builder()
                .query(builder -> builder.bool(builder1 -> builder1.must(queryList)))
                .script(script)
                .build();


        try {
            UpdateByQueryResponse updateByQueryResponse = elasticClientBuilder.getESClient(isPreview)
                    .updateByQuery(updateByQueryRequest);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

I have tried too many solutions available none of them seems to be working
